# Find a basis given a span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the subspace $W = \{ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \;:\; a + b = c + d\}$ of $P_3$. Finally, what is the dimension of $W$?

I'm unsure of how to go about solving something like this, thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts, say as to the dimension?  Hint:  how many parameters does it take to specify an element of $W$?

Comment: I really have absolutely no idea how to solve this at all. I just need a worked out example as I have never seen one worked out before.

Comment: Well, the dimension of $P_3$ is $4$ so there aren't very many possibilities.  Can you find an element of $P_3$ which isn't in $W$?  That would tell you that $\dim W≤ 3$.

Comment: I don't know how to find an element of p3.

Comment: @frillybob Observe that your set's condition is the same as $\;a+b-c-d=0\;$ . Now, to solve this, it is enough you choose *freely* any three of these parameters, say $\;a,b,c\;$ , and then the fourth one is completely determined. This tells you the dimension is $\;3\;$ . Try now to come up with three vectors in $\;W\;$ which are linearly independent.

Comment: Try a simplified problem first: in the 3-dimensional space, find a basis for the subspace $W = \{(a, b, c) \, : \, a+b = 0\}$.  What is the dimension of $W$?  If this is still difficult, start by reviewing the definitions of basis and dimension.

Comment: @frillybob  $P_3$ presumably just means polynomials of degree $3$.  So, $x^3\in P_3$. Is $x^3\in W$?

Comment: @frillybob Is it okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Each element of $W$ has the form

$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+(a+b-c)$

$=a(x^3+1)+b(x^2+1)+c(x-1)$

thus

$F=(x^3+1,x^2+1,x-1)$ is a spanning set.

let us prove that the three polynoms of the family $F$, are independent.

Assume
$A(x^3+1)+B(x^2+1)+C(x-1)=0x^3+0x^2+0x+0$
then by identification of the coefficients
we get

$A=0\;, B=0\;$ and $C=0$, thus

$F $ is a basis of $W$.

$W$ will have dimension $3$.

Comment: And how did you get the (x^3+1),(x^2+1) and (x-1) in the spanning set?

Comment: Each element of W is a linear  combination of these three polynoms.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that. Can you show it please?